# Probing the ios sandbox

Tags: ios, sandbox

I am currently new to ios so I do need help in this. I am trying to probe the sandbox of an iphone to retrieve any data from an application such as contacts. From what I know, I need to have understanding of c/obj c programming and understand the features of the mobile with regards to sandbox. So for my questions,

1)How should I get myself started?
2)Are there any features of the mobile regarding about sandbox should I need to understand before proceeding? (Some examples would be great)
3)Do I need to create my own application such as an app that stores contacts to probe on(using XCode)?
4)Any critical information that I missed out?

Much help is needed. Thanks. This is for educational purposes

Comment: Just start reading some tutorials. The ones on Ray Wenderlich are superb: http://www.raywenderlich.com/38557/learn-to-code-ios-apps-1-welcome-to-programming

Comment: thanks,I will read them up :)

Comment: Browsing through the link it contains tutorials on creating ios apps with tutorials on c programming. What I am more concerned is on the sandbox part. Hope someone would clarify this part with regards to the questions

Comment: You are looking at this in too focussed a way. If you are expecting to find a "tutorial" that you can just tailor a bit to suit your needs, you may be lucky; but this won't help you make any changes, implement features, or even debug the inevitable problems. You could do worse than looking at the Apple tutorials [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html) which help you to learn the iOS paradigm and design patterns. You'll also get experience in reading the documentation. Look into the AddressBook Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sandbox is given to you by iOS, no need to set up or anything. The sandbox means that your app is limited in accessing system resources, specifically file system, documents and settings. It can play only in its "sandbox". But there is no mock like environment that you can use for testing.

For more info on the sandbox, check out the [iOS Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html).